# Using Python in R with reticulate package - Numpy not found

Tags: r, numpy, scikit-learn, anaconda, reticulate

I am starting using `reticulate` package that allows using Python within R environment and wanted to perform mean-shift clustering with `sklearn`. So here's my attempt:

```
> library(reticulate)
> np <- import('numpy')
> sklearn <- import('sklearn')
> sklearn.MeanShift <- sklearn$cluster$MeanShift
> x <- matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2)
> sklearn.MeanShift(x)
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  Evaluation error: Required version of NumPy not available: installation of Numpy >= 1.6 not found.
```

As you can see, `numpy` was not found while calling `sklearn` function while it is imported without a problem with `reticulate::import`. I have also checked the version of `numpy` I have in conda prompt and it is 1.15.4. Also `py_numpy_available()` returns false. My `reticulate` config are:

```
python:         C:\Users\jakes\ANACON~1\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/jakes/ANACON~1/python37.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\jakes\ANACON~1
version:        3.7.1 (default, Oct 28 2018, 08:39:03) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]
scikit-learn:   [NOT FOUND]

python versions found: 
 C:\Users\jakes\ANACON~1\python.exe
 C:\Users\jakes\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please don't use the `r` tag for non-r questions.

Comment: @NelsonGon, `reticulate` is a package that allows using `python` in `r` so how is it non-r question? I think the whole setup is on `r` side.

Comment: If someone simply looks at this question, there's no way to tell it's an R question. One would see python code and assume it's a python question. Perhaps make it more explicit?

Comment: Ok, I've just edited to point it out at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/367) for more information.

I got the same error while trying to call a function from a python script with R objects as arguments. Apparently this happens because Python hasn't been added to your PATH (that is what was adviced during Anaconda installation), which prevents reticulate from finding numpy when initializing python.
Adding python to your PATH in R before initializing it with reticulate is what solved the issue for me. So from the aformentioned thread:

```
if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows") Sys.setenv(PATH= paste("C:/Anaconda3/Library/bin",Sys.getenv()["PATH"],sep=";"))
library(reticulate)
```